# Can't use window controls on maximized windows

Tags: unity, 13.04, window, maximized

When I maximise a window and hover my mouse where the window controls should be, they do not appear however if I hover my mouse over the file menu bar, they do appear but as soon as I move my mouse back, it disappears as if my mouse was elsewhere. This is only on maximised windows and I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

Mouse over menu:
[image: Mouse over menu, controls shown]

Mouse over window controls:
[image: Mouse over window controls, controls not shown]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be related to Steam and can be fixed by restarting (exiting then reopening) Steam.

The reason the old solution worked (posted below) was because of (what I believe to be) a bug which I have reported here, https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/2799, but I'm not sure when it'll be fixed. *The bug caused Steam to exit when opening a 13.04 Unity logout or shutdown dialog.*

I've reported the window controls bug here: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/2919

Original solution:

> Fixed by opening a logout or shutdown dialog in Unity with Ubuntu 13.04. Opening a dialog and cancelling it will fix the problem.

Comment: A friend of mine is facing this problem on 12.04.3. Your post was very useful, thank you very much. I'd like to add that, as workaround, given that my friend can't minimize because of steam and he uses the steam chat as a way of communicating with friends (so closing steam is a bad option), he just added a keyboard shortcut for minimizing the window.

Comment: You can always close Steam then reopen it again, but this is a fine workaround.